# Testing a rails 3.2 engine with Test::Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having great difficulty testing a rails 3.2 engine.

I do the following:

```
# generate the engine
rails plugin new myengine --mountable
cd myengine

# generate user resource
rails generate scaffold user name email password_digest

# try to run rake test from myengine root folder
rake test 
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<myengine::UsersControllerTest>
```

So I try this:

```
cd test/dummy
rake myengine:install:migrations
rake db:migrate db:test:prepare  
rake test # from within test/dummy
=> # nothing happens, no output
```

Back to the engine's root folder

```
cd ../.. 
rake test
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<myengine::UsersControllerTest>
```

I suspect the undefined method refers to the following line at the top of my UsersContrllerTest:

```
setup do
  @user = users(:one)
end
```

I do have fixtures, they were generated along with the rest of the scaffold, and I haven't messed with any code, just done the steps outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that someone opened a ticket 8 months ago, and the Rails team closed it off, without fixing it. The steps to resolve are detailed in the comments for [this Github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4971).